# Limit/Track outbound traffic

Tags: linux, users

In my server there are untrusted users. There is a risk that one of the users may perform excessive http/https requests to another remote server and I may have problems if that happens.

I have heard `tcpdump` is the most powerful tool for network analysis/tracking, but I'm not aware of any way to be able to track which users are sending http/https requests and what are their sending rate.

If something happens, I need to identify the culprit.

In your opinion, which is the best tool/software tools for the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Tcpdump was created for debugging network issues, not for persistent traffic monitoring.

The best tool for analyze and control user's traffic is proxy-server such as [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/Intro/):

> Squid is a fully-featured HTTP/1.0 proxy which is almost (but not
>   quite - we're getting there!) a fully-featured HTTP/1.1 proxy. Squid
>   offers a rich access control, authorization and logging environment to
>   develop web proxy and content serving applications. Squid offers a
>   rich set of traffic optimization options, most of which are enabled by
>   default for simpler installation and high performance.

You can use Squid with [LightSquid](http://lightsquid.sourceforge.net/) - this is light log analizer for Squid.